# Use vba to get median on certain file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm just starting in VBA and I can't find out a solution to get the median of each id on the 1st column :
[image]

So the original file is column A and B.
The result is column D & E.

1st step is to find the occurences of column A (ID)
Then get calculate the median of their result (column B)
Then write in column D and E the result for each occurence...

Thank you very much for your help

EDITED

Found my answer thank's to @Michal Turczyn help :

WARNING, Datas must be sorted by column A first (else this code won't work)

```
Option Explicit

Sub CalcMedian()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, id As Long, sizeTableMedian As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim table() As Double
Dim medTab As Double, val As Double, t As Long, u As Long, k As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

u = 1

For i = 1 To lastRow

    id = Cells(i, 1).Value
    k = i
    sizeTableMedian = 0

    While id = Cells(k + 1, 1).Value
        sizeTableMedian = sizeTableMedian + 1
        k = k + 1
    Wend

    ReDim table(sizeTableMedian)

    t = 0
    For j = i To i + sizeTableMedian
        val = Cells(j, 2)
        table(t) = val
        t = t + 1
    Next

    medTab = WorksheetFunction.Median(table)

    Cells(u, 4).Value = id
    Cells(u, 5).Value = medTab

    u = u + 1
    i = i + sizeTableMedian
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it without VBA, just paste following formula in E1 column:
`=median(if(A:A=D1, B:B))`, when accepting, don't press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and drag it down.

If you want VBA, here's code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CalcMedian()
Dim i As Long, id As Long, lastRow As Long, j As Long, k As Long, numbers() As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To 3
    ReDim numbers(lastRow) As Long
    k = 0
    id = Cells(i, 4).Value
    For j = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(j, 1).Value = id Then
            numbers(k) = Cells(j, 2).Value
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve numbers(k - 1) As Long
    Cells(i, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Median(numbers)

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This will be an array formula, CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Comment: why does it need to be an array formula?  should work without no? Median already expects an array.

Comment: Ok thank you for the trick but I would like to do it with VBA because I'm doing a tutorial in the same time and it's hard for me. To understand tables in vba. I would like to stock values in a table before I do the median for example.

Comment: Thank you for you help,
But, firstly, your result give me 4 4 6 (instead of 3.5 4.15 6)
Secondly, would you have a trick in the case you want to fill in column D first ? Because your code works if column D exist but in my real file, there are probably 45000 ID in column A. (in VBA would be fantastic).
Anyway, thank's for your code I still working on it.

Comment: I rekon it would be easier to sort by column A first and then while column A value is still the same, add column B value in a table for the median ?
But I can't find out how to change the size of my table as it depends of how many occurence I have in my column A

Comment: I found out thank's to you thank you I edited my post with the solution